# Having trouble with the getBoolean method in shared preferences, always shows true despite of the value being changed on Disk

Tags: java, android, cs50

I a working on Pokedex by cs50 and facing a lot of trouble. I am always getting  true when i call this..

```
val = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), false);
    if (val == false){
        buttonView.setText("Catch");
    } else {
        buttonView.setText("Release");
    }
```

I know the chnages are getting saved to the preference because , this is working properly when i trigger the button;

```
public void toggleCatch(View view) {


    boolean val = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), false);

    if (!val){
        buttonView.setText("Release1");
        getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), true).commit();
    } else {
        buttonView.setText("Catch1");
        getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), false).commit();
    }


}
```

this is my full code of the activity

```
package edu.harvard.cs50.pokedex;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public class PokemonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private TextView numberTextView;
    private TextView type1TextView;
    private TextView type2TextView;
    private TextView descView;
    private Button buttonView;
    private ImageView spriteView;
    private String url;
    private String desc_url;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private int id;
    boolean val;
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokemon);

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        nameTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_name);
        numberTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_number);
        type1TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_type1);
        type2TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokemon_type2);
        buttonView = findViewById(R.id.catch_button);
        spriteView = findViewById(R.id.spriteView);
        descView = findViewById(R.id.descView);
        load();

        val = getPreferences(
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE
         ).getBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(),false);
        if (val == false){
            buttonView.setText("Catch");
        } else {
            buttonView.setText("Release");
        }


    }
    private class DownloadSpriteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openStream());
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("cs50", "Download sprite error", e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            spriteView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
    public void load() {
        type1TextView.setText("");
        type2TextView.setText("");

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    nameTextView.setText(response.getString("name"));
                    numberTextView.setText(String.format("#%03d", response.getInt("id")));
                    id = response.getInt("id");

                    desc_url = String.format("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/%d/", id);

                    JsonObjectRequest request2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, desc_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray desc_array = response.getJSONArray("flavor_text_entries");
                                Log.d("ved", "Flavor text entries loaded");
                                for (int i = 0; i < desc_array.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject desc = desc_array.getJSONObject(i);
                                    if (desc.getJSONObject("language").getString("name").equals("en")) {
                                        descView.setText(desc.getString("flavor_text"));
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("ved", "desc" + e);

                            }
                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("ved", "Pokemon desc error", error);
                        }
                    });
                    requestQueue.add(request2);






                    JSONArray typeEntries = response.getJSONArray("types");
                    JSONObject spriteEntries = response.getJSONObject("sprites");
                    String img_url = spriteEntries.getString("front_default");
                    new DownloadSpriteTask().execute(img_url);
                    for (int i = 0; i < typeEntries.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject typeEntry = typeEntries.getJSONObject(i);
                        int slot = typeEntry.getInt("slot");
                        String type = typeEntry.getJSONObject("type").getString("name");

                        if (slot == 1) {
                            type1TextView.setText(type);
                        }
                        else if (slot == 2) {
                            type2TextView.setText(type);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("cs50", "Pokemon json error", e);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("cs50", "Pokemon details error", error);
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(request);




    }


    //shared presferences intially all values to false


    @SuppressLint({"ApplySharedPref", "SetTextI18n"})
    public void toggleCatch(View view) {


        boolean val = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), false);

        if (!val){
            buttonView.setText("Release1");
            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), true).commit();
        } else {
            buttonView.setText("Catch1");
            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), false).commit();
        }


    }
}
```

I have to implement save to my preferences such that it remember if I,hve catched ny pokemons , if I reopen the app it much display the same..

Comment: `=` is an assignment, `==` has to be used for comparisons.

Comment: As it's boolean you can directly use that value in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

As variable type is boolean, you can directly use it as condition in if block.

```
val = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), false);
    if (!val){
        buttonView.setText("Catch");
    } else {
        buttonView.setText("Release");
    }
```

Comment: thanks but still that doesnt solve the problem cause the val variable is always returning true despite of changing its value to false

Comment: Could you please add your `getPreferences` method's code in Question?

Comment: I hve suppiled full code in the question now, thanks in advanced for the help

Comment: Instead of this line `getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), true).commit();` try with `.setBoolean`.

Comment: hiee I tried but can you please tell how exactly or on which object i must use setBoolean?

Comment: My doubt is with this line of code, here you are toggling your boolean variable using putBoolean, whether it's working fine or not sure. So instead of `putBoolean` you can try `setBoolean` in all your code.
`getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(nameTextView.getText().toString(), true).commit();`

Comment: Just do toggling, if it's true then make it false, and if false then make it true.
`if (!val){
         
            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().setBoolean(true).commit();
        } else {         getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().setBoolean(false).commit();
        }`

Comment: hiee thanks a lott , but when I put my oncreate code inside the load function it worked like expected ..

Comment: Just debug once, it's going inside first if condition then check with what it's setting for same. And next time whether same flag get toggle or not.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your code. Instead of checking if `val` is false, you're setting `false` to it:

```
if (val = false)
```

You can fix that by

```
if (val == false)
```

Please, check if that's what is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks I checked but still, the value of variable val is coming out to be true